# C Language: Since there is no "byte" primitive, is using a "char" the exact equivalent?

Tags: c, types

I have a bit that I am toggling in my program, and was wondering if I can do this:

```
    char *toggle = // some address;
    *toggle = 0; // initially

    // if(something)
    //    *toggle = 1;

    // other code that continues to toggle under certain conditions...
```

But dereferencing a char* treats the value like a char, nothing more and nothing less. So I was wondering if it is a valid method of storing the 1 and 0 (which are integers)?

Comment: yes. Even alphabets are assigned to some integer value right...

Comment: What is your point ? For computers, everything is _binary_ integers, _char_ type just decides the memory space. So, even if it is char it will be stored as a number (integer) in memory.

Comment: FYI, it is preferred in C to use `int` for boolean flags in functions and `bool` if you are using C99 with `<stdbool.h>`.  You won't do anyone a favor by using `char` instead.

Comment: @Dietrich That is not true. It is very common to use char as boolean type, especially on small microcontroller applications. Why allocate 2 or 4 bytes when you can allocate 1?

Comment: @Lundin - it can be a false economy, depending on the microcontroller. Often *more instructions are required* to manipulate a single byte than to manipulate a whole word, so your saving of 3 bytes actually *costs* a couple of dozen bytes. (I've verified this on a couple of chips we use here, but obviously this depends greatly on the compiler, the chip and what kind of space is at a premium, program flash or data.)

Comment: @detly: Of course. If you don't know what you are doing, you will get problems no matter CPU. You'll have to know if the CPU has instruction support or not for bytes, and if alignment is an issue. If you have some sort of Intel:ish offspring, using bytes for bool may not be ideal. What you refer to however is additional _program instructions_, those are stored in program memory, not RAM. You will still be saving RAM at the expense of flash, the former is often the most rare one in embedded systems.

Comment: @Lundin - you may not be saving RAM if the compiler emits code for manipulating a word-sized chunk of data that contains your byte-packed information :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a completely valid method. `char` can be treated like an integer <strike>in most cases</strike> - and as such you can also do arithmetic on variables of type `char`.

Comment: Most? `char` is an integral type. Character literals have type `int`. You probably want to specify signedness, since plain `char` can be either or, but it _is_ an integral type.

Comment: @Chris Lutz: Ah, I was thinking on the lines of C++ where `char*` is sometimes treated differently due to all the overloading specializations. Now that I think about, none of these apply to C... will fix.

Comment: I use the unsigned counterpart most of the time, especially when I have to deal with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 2):

char and char* are different.

The type char, under the hood is a single byte large.  Yes, you could implicitly cast it to an integer if you wanted to (-128 to 128 if signed, 0 to 256 if unsigned).

char* is a pointer.  The size of a pointer is dependent on your system (generally 32-bit or 64-bit).  Your code snippet is effectively using a pointer to represent a boolean value.  While it will work, you'll get weird looks from peers reviewing your code.  Using a char* to represent a number consumes just as much space as using an int (also 4 bytes, aka 32 bits).

Between the two, use char.  Better than that, use short ints (con: larger in size, pro: future readers will know you are talking about an integral type).

Comment: If you're worried about people knowing you intend to use an integral type, use `[u]int8_t` from `stdint.h`, or have `typedef signed char byte; typedef unsigned char ubyte;` in a header somewhere to make it clear for people.

Comment: @ChrisLutz: `typedef signed char byte;` `typedef unsigned char ubyte;`

Comment: @DietrichEpp - Wow, that's not something I usually do. Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`char` is the 8-bit integer type in C, as someone mentioned everything in your computer is binary numbers. So there is nothing magic with the char type just because it is often used to store ASCII characters, which of course is a binary number too.

Note however that there is a subtle difference between the common integer types (short, int, long) and char. If you just write for example `int` without the unsigned/signed keyword in front of it, it is signed by default. This is not true for chars though, they could be signed *or* unsigned by default, this is implementation-specific behavior and depends on the compiler.

To avoid problems like this, always use safe, typedef:ed names. If you are using a C99 compiler you can find such in stdint.h. If not, make a header of your own:

```
typedef unsigned char  uint8_t;
typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
// and so on
```

---

EDIT:
If  you are a C language fetishist, then add the following snippet to the header:

```
#include <limits.h>
#if CHAR_BIT != 8
  #error "Obscure system! Your compiler is too dumb to know about wchar_t!" \
         "You should really upgrade to one made after 1989!"
#endif
```

Comment: I almost gave you +1, but then I saw your line about `uint16_t`. No, no, don't do that. where you can be relatively sure (guaranteed by POSIX) that `char` is 8 bit, there is no such guarantee for `short` being 16 bit wide. Just leave that out, it even isn't about the question, here.

Comment: There is certainly no requirement in C that `char` should be an "8-bit integer type".

Comment: @Jens If you haven't got a C99 compiler, then you must write a typedef header with these types for every platform. **It will obviously not be portable.** Every professional C programmer knows about this and has such a header file ported for every platform they need.

Comment: @Lundin, you were just saying "make a header of your own". As @unwind says, even your assumption about the 8 bits of `char` is only valid in certain contexts. Also, if every professional C programmer knew things like that, we would have much less questions here.

Comment: @unwind: Fine. Edited the post. It really added value to the discussion.

Comment: @Jens All of the _professional_ ones know about it. But yes, there are of course also a lot of beginners and quacks (the whole software industry is roughly 10% pro, 40% newbies and 50% quacks). Writing portable programs isn't really a task for a beginner anyhow - hopefully all who are new to C/C++ can pick a C99 compiler today, if only for stdint.h.

Comment: Anyway, if you _don't_ make a header of your own but try to write portable programs, you are more or less guaranteed to screw up on signedness of char, signedness of integers, signedness of integer literals, implicit integer promotions, implicit balancing promotions, etc. You'd have to write an incredibly awful header to come up with one that's actually worse than all the problems asociated with C's native primitive data types.